# validate only on check php jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Html code

```
<form id="cekform">
    <input class="cek" name="cek[1]" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
    <input class="cek" name="cek[2]" type="checkbox" value="2">
    <input class="cek" name="cek[3]" type="checkbox" value="3">
</form>
```

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cekform").validate({});
  $('.cek.true').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      max:2,
      messages: {
        required:  "your custom message",
        number:  "your custom message",
        max:  "your custom message"
      }
    }); 
  });
}); 
</script>
```

this js to make change class input

```
$('input[class^="cek"]').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).addClass('true');

    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('true');
    }
});
```

i want validate only input which had checked, but when itray my code validation didnt work
can anyone help me ?

Comment: why $('input[class^="cek"]').click and not $(',cek').click ?

Comment: coz i looping my form with php